# css vertical align inside vertical align

Tags: css

My goal is to create 3 vertically aligned div's where one div has a vertical bar of the parent's height (`border-right`). The parent can have a fixed height, which in turn should make it possible to use vertical alignment using css (I know that flexbox can solve it, but I am really asking about the vertical-align behavior here).

The following snippet shows a CSS behavior that I don't understand:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    <div>
      Part B<br>Part B  
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="c">
    <span>Part C</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
.parent {
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.a {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}

.b {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.c {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  padding-right: 10px;
  height: 50px;
}

.span {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;

}
```

I was expecting the div `C` to be vertically aligned but it's aligned on top. If I remove the `height` property from class `.c`, then the alignment is correct but the vertical bar is too short. I created the following fiddle for this question: 
http://jsfiddle.net/04e2ckxm/2/

Comment: Try using `display: table-cell`? See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change all of the children `<div>`'s CSS from `display: inline-block` to `display: table-cell`.

This creates the following (desired) result:

[image: screenshot]

See working example on [JSfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/04e2ckxm/4/).

Comment: Wow, that seems simple to fix. But is there a rationale behind this?

Comment: @shaft The `table-cell` in HTML simply allows for centered vertical positioning. And I'm glad I helped!

Answer (score 2):

> (I know that flexbox can solve it, but I am really asking about the vertical-align behavior here).

In your example, the text is vertically centered because its parent is the height of the text:

`vertical-align: middle`                    `vertical-align: bottom`                `vertical-align: top`

[image: Example 1]

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 40px;
}
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F8BBD0;
}
.top > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.middle > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bottom > div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent middle">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
    <br>Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
    <br>Part C
    <br>Part C
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent bottom">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
    <br>Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
    <br>Part C
    <br>Part C
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent top">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
    <br>Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
    <br>Part C
    <br>Part C
  </div>
</div>
```

When you give the element a fixed height, the blocks are vertically centered, *not their contents*:

`vertical-align: middle`                    `vertical-align: bottom`                `vertical-align: top`

[image: Example 2]

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 40px;
}
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F8BBD0;
}
.top > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.middle > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bottom > div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.c {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent middle">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
    <br>Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
    <br>Part C
    <br>Part C
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent bottom">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
    <br>Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
    <br>Part C
    <br>Part C
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent top">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
    <br>Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
    <br>Part C
    <br>Part C
  </div>
</div>
```

To illustrate this further, we can give each div a different fixed height:

`vertical-align: middle`                    `vertical-align: bottom`                `vertical-align: top`

[image: Example 3]

```css
body {
  background: #FFF;
}
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 40px;
}
.parent > div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #F8BBD0;
}
.top > div {
  vertical-align: top;
}
.middle > div {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.bottom > div {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
.a {
  height: 50px;
}
.b {
  height: 100px;
}
.c {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent middle">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent bottom">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent top">
  <div class="a">
    Part A
  </div>
  <div class="b">
    Part B
  </div>
  <div class="c">
    Part C
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You say that the blocks are centered vertically but not their contents. This is why I called the question "css vertical align inside vertical align". Because I wanted to make a vertical alignment inside the content. If you look at the `.span` class, you'll see that it also has `vertical-align:middle`. For me the example shows that vertical alignment inside vertical alignment is not allowed in css (for inline blocks), but that doesn't make much sense, hence the question. And it gets even stranger: when I make the span fixed height, the middle becomes top: http://jsfiddle.net/04e2ckxm/5/

Comment: @shaft - It's just how vertical-align works with inline elements. It aligns the blocks themselves, so the text is not affected. If you wanted to vertically center the text itself in a inline block element, you have to use a little trick [like this example here.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lbpnec75/)